# Check death summary after a hero dies in a replay

Tags: dota-2

So I'm watching a replay in Dota 2. Imagine a situation a Beastmaster is killed. I want to know who did how much damage to Beastmaster to kill him. How do I check this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use http://www.dotabuff.com/ which shows you this information in the Kills tab of a particular match.  I'm not sure if this feature requires a paid subscription or not though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't remember good features for this in replays. But you can check battle log. Top left, third from the left (including go to menu-button). Little gamepad button (is actually a tree log). Click it. Hope this helps